# CSS Horizontal menu using unordered list bent out of shape

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: #036;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/u3gau3qf/

Why is this menu looking like stairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `float: left` on your `a` elements, so your `li` elements are still on their own lines.

The reason you're seeing a staircase effect is because the `a` elements are taller than the `li`s they are contained in, so they push the next link's `a` element forward. If you use your browser's developer tools, you can see that the rendered height of the `li` is smaller than that of its child, so each `a` element is occupying some space in the `li` that comes after it.

You want the following CSS:

```
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

To see in action how the heights are mismatched, here's a demo. The borders define the bounding box of the `li` elements, and the backgrounds are applied to the `a` elements:

```css
ul {
 padding-left: 0;
 background-color: #036;
}

ul li {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 0.2em 1em;
 color: white;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Per what I read float need to have widths. Do I apply this to `a` or `i` elements?

Comment: Elements with a float do not need to have defined widths; they will take the width of their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating a horizontal nav menu you should add a inline block style to your list items. Try this in your css:

```
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I though floats could do the same

Comment: You could but you would have to introduce the 'clear' property. 'inline-block' just lets you avoid using any extra css declarations for clear. Keep in mind that 'inline' is not compatible for IE6-IE7. [Check here](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's time to abandon all version of IE except IE 8 so I am not worried about anything less than IE 8. Though IE 8 is becoming obsolete too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not defining a float or inline-block attribute on the li tag, so it appears as a full width block. The float in your example is only on the a tag **inside** the li, so if you just move your float out to the li you should be good. Better yet, use inline-block as suggested in other comments.